# jmeter aggregation listener not producing aggregated results

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan that is composed of a single threadgroup a number of custom java request samplers as children of the thread group and an aggregation listener.

The aggregation listener is writing to a file which includes a row for each invocation of each one of the java samplers. However it is not performing or writing any aggregations.

The default summary however *is* being produced and written to the log and that contains the aggregated requests/per second etc that I would expect from the aggregation listener.

Can anyone tell me how to either :a) Get the aggregation listener to produce aggregations rather than just a csv file containing rows with the results of each java sampler request? b) Redirect the output of the default test summary to another file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use listeners as they don't add any value, they just create memory and disk IO overhead. You should be [running your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) telling JMeter to store the results in a file using [`-l command-line argument`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
   ```

   Once your test is done you should be able to open `results.jtl` file with the listener of your choice and see the results and export them into a file if needed. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) guide for detailed explanation regarding why you should not be using JMeter Listeners for anything but tests development and/or debugging

   If you need to generate the Aggregate Report in unattended manner without interim manual step you will need [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), using it you will be able to generate different tables and charts from the `.jtl` results files
2. For the moment you have only 2 options of storing summariser output: [stdout] (console)[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and *jmeter.log* file. You can play with JMeter [log4j configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) to choose what you want to store there.

Comment: Dmitri T - thanks for your answer. I have been using the command-line non-GUI mode and I have been writing the results using `-l results.jtl` I assumed that because I had included the aggregation report listener in the test plan after the java samplers that the results.jtl would contain aggregated results similar to those published by the summariser. I found however that the results.jtl just contained a row for each request from the java samplers with no aggregation. If I understand you correctly you are saying this is expected and I shoud use another tool to aggregate results after the test?

Comment: You can use JMeter in GUI mode, add a listener, load the jtl (by clicking on the browse button in the listener), and you'll be able to see the metrics.

Answer (score 0):

To get summarized results add to your test plan [Generate Summary Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Generate_Summary_Results):

> Generates a summary of the test run so far to the log file and/or standard output

Update interval in jmeter.properties to your needs

```
 # interval between summaries (in seconds) default 3 minutes
 #summariser.interval=30
```

Comment: Please expand this answer to a complete solution. What should we expect to find behind the link? How does that solve the problem?